# Rescale a GCRect to a specific CGSize

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, cgaffinetransform, cgrect

I have a question about scale operation of a frame to a specific size.

I have a CGRect and would to resize it to a specific CGSize.

I would to move the center of this CGRect in proportion to my rescale value.

Comment: Understand that a CGRect is just a C structure containing 4 values -- `origin.x`, `origin.y`, `size.width`, `size.height`.  And a CGSize is just `width` and `height`.  There are a number of functions defined to operate on them but sometimes it's clearer (and easier to remember) to operate on the pieces directly.

Answer (score 0):

If by chance you're modifying a `UIView`, you could take this approach:

```
CGPoint previousCenter = view.center;
// Set width and height here:
view.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x,view.frame.origin.y, width, height); 
view.center = previousCenter;
```

That'll maintain the center point while changing the size of the view.

I am a little confused by your question, so I may not be answering it correctly. If you are using a `CGAffineTransform` to scale, as your tags suggest, that's another matter entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CGRectInset(rect, x, y)`. This will inset the CGRect by `x` and `y`, and push the origin in by `x` and `y`.  (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectInset)

```
CGSize targetSize = CGSizeMake(100.0f, 100.0f);
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(50.0f, 50.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f);
rect = CGRectInset(rect, roundf((rect.size.width - targetSize.width) / 2.0f), roundf((rect.size.height - targetSize.height) / 2.0f);
```

Edit: Note that I'm using the difference between the two sizes, halved. My justification here is that `CGRectInset` will affect the entire rect. What I mean by that is...

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10);
rect = CGRectInset(rect, 2, 2);

rect is now a CGRect with (2, 2, 6, 6)
```